# Extract FCM server keys from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, devops

We have almost a hundred apps/projects in Firebase that we need to fetch FCM server keys for. We want to automate the process of fetching the server keys for the push server.

Is there any way we could get the keys from Firebase through the SDK or firebase-cli ?