# Can I get FCM Server Key programatically?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a project where I'm automating projects creation on Google Cloud / Firebase.

These projects will use onesignal for push management, and I want to automate the creation of project on both services and integrate them.

To configure a firebase project on OneSignal I need two informations:

- Firebase Project Number
- Firebase Cloud Messaging Server Key

I already have project number from previous steps. But I can't find any info about retriving Server Key programatically.

The only reference I've found is this unanswered question:
[Extract FCM server keys from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066004/extract-fcm-server-keys-from-firebase)

The key I want to get is this:
[image]

Is there anyway to get this key programatically?

Thx in advance.